# Why does Edge change encoding ="UTF-8" to encoding ISO-8859-1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xsd-validation

The browser Edge of its own volition converts an XSD file from encoding"UTF-8" to ISO-8859-1. 
My questions are  1. Is this an EDGE peculiarity,or is EDGE doing it because UTF-8 was deprecated when I was not looking, and replaced by ISO-8859-1. 2. Why the processing differences between browsers, 3. Is there a globally preferred encoding structure. Have read the W3 schools and  Stackoverflow articles, informative yes but no recommendations.
I would like to opt a single standard for processing all my XML files (which there will be many) across my application. Should I just use ISO-8859-1. Please guide direct, help I really feel illiteracy on my part taking an upper hand.

The facts are a. Visual Studio created the file using UTF, b.I have no special characters/ symbols in the associated Xml file nor will I need them in the future, c.the chrome browser ignores (does not display) the following XML tag which is displayed in edge '' d. Both browsers process the file:/// ...file.

The code used to test the xsd reference is  file:///D:\prjClimateControl\prgrms\slnsVsTo\prjV00G00Jun0619\sysdocXml1.xsd

The xml tag in the edge display is 
but is displayed as

no error messages the file displays correctly but changes the endcoding